# How to create Silverlight 3 Themes?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

The new Silverlight 3 features page says:

*Developers can now theme applications by applying styles to their Silverlight 3 applications and changing them at runtime.*

But I can't find any information about this.  I would like to create a theme for may app to define button styles/etc...

Can someone let me know how to do this or point me to a web tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see Karen Corby's talk at Mix09 online?

Around the 43-44 minute mark of her talk she shows off dynamic styling with Silverlight 3 and she has some example code on her blog.

[Karen's talk](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T16F) on the [Mix video site](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09).
[Karen's blog](http://scorbs.com/) which had sample code and slides